# The HTML Object tag is not displaying in Firefox 34 and 35

Tags: firefox

I have a website which uses the HTML Object tag to display a PDF, via an ASHX handler.

It has worked fine on all browsers, until recent versions of Firefox.

The HTML Object tag is not displaying in Firefox 34 and 35.  It displays in 33, and in all recent versions of Chrome and IE.

Any ideas about changes to Firefox that might cause it to ignore this tag?